# How do you use interfaces with two extend parameters used?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to understand the code when using typescript in react-table and I come across these kinds of interfaces

```
 export interface TableInstance<D extends object = {}>
    extends Omit<TableOptions<D>, 'columns' | 'pageCount'>,
        UseTableInstanceProps<D> {}
```

notice the two extends keywords in the interface. A table instance is generated when calling

```
    export function useTable<D extends object = {}>(
    options: TableOptions<D>,
    ...plugins: Array<PluginHook<D>>
): TableInstance<D>;
```

after which I can access the `TableInstance` properties inherited from `UseTableInstanceProps`

Am I write by saying that `TableInstance` is an object that inherits the properties of `Omit` and `UseTableInstanceProps`?

What does this Omit mean? Are there any resources that can help me understand this kind of syntax?

```
/**
 * Construct a type with the properties of T except for those in type K.
 */
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit, Pick and Exclude are TypeScript utility types as documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#introduction).

Hence react-table is creating its own version of Omit i.e. it's not the same as the [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) TypeScript utility type. As for the "keyof" keyword refer to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).